# Best way to model a string matrix (postgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, database-design

My goal is to make this as convenient as possible (i.e. least external tables lookups in application) and efficient (least redundant indexes)

I need to model data that, without any optimization, would ideally look like:

```
.______________________________.
|   en-US   |  pt-BR   | zn-CN | ...
|===========|==========|=======|
|university | academia |  大学 |
| self-made |  NULL    |  自制 |
|  NULL     | saudade  |  思   |
'-----------'----------'-------'
```

the main application use case is to fetch words from one locale and find the other locale.

The caveats are:

- I do not know the number of locales. Ideally they can be created by the application on runtime, but i am fine making a new locale be a Ops event that require downtime and alter table.
- There is no "main" locale.
- If we extract terms into a `locale, word` table, there is the problem of `A,B == B,A`, but we can work around this by having a logic on normalizing B,A as A,B to avoid N^N relations. But would be nice if the schema does not have this problem at all.
- bonus: i'd like to avoid repeating the words/indexes all over, as is done with gnu gettext data files.

ideally queries would be as convenient as `select en-US from words where zn-CN='nihao'`

was playing with some alternatives on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b22dddd5e7b70cdf9f61500ef076cda9), but none are even close to optimal.

> ```
> create table A (
>   locale text NOT NULL,
>   word text NOT NULL,
>   primary key (locale, word)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into A values
> ('en-US', 'hi'),
> ('zn-CN', 'nihao'),
> ('pt-BR', 'oi');
>
> select * from A limit 5;
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
>
> locale | word 
> :----- | :----
> en-US  | hi   
> zn-CN  | nihao
> pt-BR  | oi
> ```

> ```
> create table B (
>   locale text NOT NULL,
>   word text NOT NULL,
>   locale2 text NOT NULL,
>   word2 text NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY(locale, word, locale2, word2),
>   FOREIGN KEY(locale,word) REFERENCES A(locale,word),
>   FOREIGN KEY(locale2,word2) REFERENCES A(locale,word)
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

table B would be noisy, but would allow queries close to the ideal. But i am afraid to even start looking if the engine indexing would be optimal with just those keys.

> ```
> -- only 3 words is already a mess without application normalization logic
> insert into B values
> ('en-US', 'hi', 'pt-BR', 'oi'),
> ('pt-BR', 'oi', 'en-US', 'hi'),
> ('en-US', 'hi', 'zn-CN', 'nihao'),
> ('pt-BR', 'oi', 'zn-CN', 'nihao'),
> ('zn-CN', 'nihao', 'en-US', 'hi'),
> ('zn-CN', 'nihao', 'pt-BR', 'oi');
>
> select * from B limit 10;
> ```
>
> ```
> 6 rows affected
>
> locale | word  | locale2 | word2
> :----- | :---- | :------ | :----
> en-US  | hi    | pt-BR   | oi   
> pt-BR  | oi    | en-US   | hi   
> en-US  | hi    | zn-CN   | nihao
> pt-BR  | oi    | zn-CN   | nihao
> zn-CN  | nihao | en-US   | hi   
> zn-CN  | nihao | pt-BR   | oi
> ```

> ```
>      create table C (
>        locale text NOT NULL,
>        word text NOT NULL,
>        locale2 text NOT NULL,
>        word2 text NOT NULL,
>        FOREIGN KEY(locale,word) REFERENCES A(locale,word),
>        FOREIGN KEY(locale2,word2) REFERENCES A(locale,word)
>      );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> - we can probably normalize somehow by selecting precedence for locales, e.g. en-US < pt-BR < zn-CN
> insert into C values
> ('en-US', 'hi', 'pt-BR', 'oi'),
> ('en-US', 'hi', 'zn-CN', 'nihao'),
> ('pt-BR', 'oi', 'zn-CN', 'nihao');
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select word2 as translation from C where locale='en-US' and word='hi' and locale2='zn-CN';
> ```
>
> ```
> | translation |
> | :---------- |
> | nihao       |
> ```

> ```
> -- application must search on other side if locale normalization says so
> select word as translation from C where locale2='zn-CN' and word2='nihao' and locale ='en-US';
> ```
>
> ```
> | translation |
> | :---------- |
> | hi          |
> ```

...and I didn't even started to look if the engine will optimize the text keys properly when they are repeated all over the relation tables.

## the naive indexed schema

```sql
create table A (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  locale text NOT NULL,
  word text NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE  (locale, word)
);
```

```sql
insert into A (locale, word) values 
('en-US', 'hi'),
('zn-CN', 'nihao'),
('pt-BR', 'oi');
select * from A limit 5;
```

> ```
> id    locale  word
> 1     en-US   hi
> 2     zn-CN   nihao
> 3     pt-BR   oi
> ```

```
create table B (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  word1 serial references A(id),
  word2 serial references A(id),
  UNIQUE (word1,word2),
  UNIQUE (word2, word1) )

insert into B (word1, word2) values
(1, 2),
(1, 3);
select * from B;
```

> ```
> id    word1   word2
> 1     1   2
> 2     1   3
> ```

But the queries are not too convenient

> ```
> select word from A where locale='en-US' and id in (
>    select word1 from B where word2 = (
>       select id from A where locale='zn-CN' and word='nihao')
>   UNION
>    select word2 from B where word1 = (
>       select id from A where locale='zn-CN' and word='nihao')
> );
> ```

index mises everywhere

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1e83c68b2f90f883340b1d24bb1e2a36

Answer (score 1):

- Plain list `id -- locale_id -- word` is good enough.
- `INT UNSIGNED id` should be used as PK for performance as far as string search for join is slow.
- Relation of equivalence can be represented by M:N table `id1 -- id2` where each pair is unique
- Commutative duplicates can be avoided by constraint `(CHECK id1 < id2)`
- The whole nest for all locales can be fetched by single recursive CTE - even if there is no full relation graph declared. Say if A=B and B=C and C=D and there is no A=D, you'll get (A,B,C,D) as a result of `CALL nest(A)`

Then you can use something like that:
`CALL convert_word('hello', 'en_US', 'zn_CN')`;

Comment: should I optimize indexes as `INT` even if the whole table will fit in memory/cache easily? Also creating a M:N table would make the index be 4bytes*(M^N). Is it really better than the naive solution of using the matrix right away?

Comment: @gcb Int values are compared by single CPU operation. String comparisons are performed char by char complicated by charsets and collations that drive to the significant overhead. So ints (and other types internally represented as ints) are preferrable types for indexes. M:N table and (m,n) index is preferrable because the corresponding code will be way simpler than for matrix.